# double border for bottom triagle + fill animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a button in the bottom right of my site which is a triangle

Code:

```css
#top-btn a, #top-btn-BG {
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
 margin: 0; 
}

#top-btn a {
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 30px 30px 25px 35px;
  color: #707070;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

#top-btn-BG {
  display: block;
  z-index: 950;
  border-width: 0 0 100px 100px;
  border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="top-btn">
  <a href="...">up</a>
  <div id="top-btn-BG"></div>
</div>
```

I want to add a `1px color: #000;` border to the outside of the triangle (just the top left edge)

I would also like to animate the triangle in from the bottom right on hover, but this feature is less important.

Comment: Could you add visual of triangle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated the answer as per the comment**

Am not sure about (*just the top left edge*) but is this you want.?

I have used `: before` for achieving this, I have also put some `transition` for you, hope this is helpful if there is anything more please do ask me.

Change the value of `transition` to make animation slow and fast.

```
transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
```

```css
#top-btn a,
#top-btn-BG {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#top-btn a {
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 30px 30px 25px 35px;
  color: #707070;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#top-btn-BG {
  display: block;
  z-index: -7;
  bottom: -30px;
  right: -70px;
  width: 172px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  background: transparent;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

#top-btn-BG:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  z-index: 950;
  border-width: 0 0 124px 125px;
  border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  
  bottom: 100px;
  right: -2%;
  width: 42px;
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

#top-btn a:hover+#top-btn-BG:after,#top-btn-BG:hover:after {
  bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-btn">
  <a href="...">up</a>
  <div id="top-btn-BG"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, close, but I want it all the way down that side that you have it on, but just that side, Not all the way around like in the example provided below. An in terms of animation, I wanted the triangle (the red part) to animate in (from off screen)

Comment: @user3550879 I have updated the answer for you so please check it and if there is anything else please do let me know.

Comment: Soooo close. I just wanted the animation to apply to the red triangle (but you animated it perfectly) and the secondary border (black line) stays in place all the time. And perhapse it's my computer but there seems to be a delay when hovered over

Comment: @user3550879 I have updated the answer again hope this is what you looking for, by the way, there is no issue of delay in my pc. Please do check it. Hope it Helps. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code with `before` element.

```css
#top-btn a, #top-btn-BG {
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
 margin: 0; 
}

#top-btn a {
  z-index: 999;
    padding: 55px 25px 26px 55px;
    color: #707070;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 0;
    border-top: 0;
}
#top-btn a:before {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: -23px;
    top: 45px;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 150px;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}
#top-btn-BG {
  display: block;
  z-index: 950;
  border-width: 0 0 100px 100px;
  border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="top-btn">
  <a href="...">up</a>
  <div id="top-btn-BG"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: close, please refer to the answer above as it is much closer